# Silverstripe 2.4 - 3.1 Upgrade - innerJoin 'unknown column' issue

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, upgrade, silverstripe

I am trying to update a website from SS 2.4 to SS 3.1 and have been digging around the web on this issue for a while now.

The old code looks like this...

```
return DataObject::get('SupportItem', "SupportItemType = '$itemType' AND ProductPageID = $productID", null, 'INNER JOIN SupportItem_Products ON SupportItem_Products.SupportItemID = SupportItem.ID');
```

I am trying to switch out of the deprecated INNER JOIN and DataObject::get to the now current innerJoin and DataobjectName::get. This is what I have for the new code

```
$productID = $this->productToView->ID;
return SupportProductListingPage::get()->innerJoin('SupportItem_Products', '"SupportItem_Products"."SupportItemID" = "SupportItem"."ID"', null)->filter(array('SupportItemType'=>'$itemType', 'ProductPageID' => '$productID'));
```

It should be noted that the "SupportItemID" column exists in "SupportItem_Products" and the "ID" column exists in "SupportItem". However, "SupportItemID" does not exist in the "SupportItem" table.

I am receiving the below error when loading the page...

```
[User Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT count(DISTINCT "SiteTree"."ID") AS "0" FROM "SiteTree" LEFT JOIN "Page" ON "Page"."ID" = "SiteTree"."ID" INNER JOIN "SupportItem_Products" ON "SupportItem_Products"."SupportItemID" = "SupportItem"."ID" WHERE ("ProductPageID" = '$productID') AND ("SiteTree"."ClassName" IN ('SupportProductListingPage')) Unknown column 'SupportItem.ID' in 'on clause'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Manuel, welcome to stackoverflow ;)
Could you please paste the definitions of the related DataObjects in this query? At least the important values of $db, $has_one, $has_many, $many_many and $belongs_many_many ? I think then we can help you better.
In SS3.1 you can do mostly anything with ORM using `->filter()`

Comment: That could have something to do with the problem. This particular dataobject has nothing in those definitions...which I did find odd, but am not 100% sure what should be in there...

Comment: @wmk are you able to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: So it worked for 2.4. Can you paste the code for 2.4 at sspaste.org? and maybe the relavant stuff you updated so far. It's hard to help just with guessing ;) Did you use the updatescript from https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-upgrade_silverstripe ? it helps a lot, but with joins you have to fix the upgrade manually.

Comment: @wmk - SSPost doesn't seem to be working, regardless however, I had included the old code AND the new code in my original question above...

Comment: Withouth knowing the fields and relations (and what you want to do) it's really hard to help. At http://www.sspaste.com/ (or in your question) you can paste the code of the used DataObjects, (SupportItem, SupportItemPage, Product etc). Just the query is just not enough!
Just saw: it seems like SupportItem and Products are in a many_many relation. This would explain the innerJoin on the relation table SupportItem_Products.
Edit: just saw sspaste.com is down :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing the join wrongly. The error message says that `Unknown column 'SupportItem.ID' in 'on clause`.

The original starts with:

`DataObject::get('SupportItem', "SupportItemType = '`

And yours starts with:

`return SupportProductListingPage::get()->innerJoin('SupportItem_Products',`

This says basically says join SupportItem_Products with  SupportProductListingPage with a table that`s not part of your query at all.

This should be the innerjoin that you actually need (not tested of course):

```
SupportItem::get()->innerJoin('SupportItem_Products','"SupportItem_Products"."SupportItemID" = "SupportItem"."ID"');
```

With that the query should be right if the class relations are declared with the right has/belongs variables.

Also your filter bit wont probably work as expected:

`filter(array('SupportItemType'=>'$itemType', 'ProductPageID' => '$productID'))`

You are trying to use a variable inside single quotes. So either do

`'SupportItemType'=>"$itemType"` or `'SupportItemType'=>$itemType`